# Datastax Spark worker is always looking for master at 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to bring up datastax cassandra in analytics mode by using "dse cassandra -k -s". I am using DSE 5.0 sandbox on a single node setup.

I have configured the spark-env.sh with SPARK_MASTER_IP as well as SPARK_LOCAL_IP to point to my LAN IP.

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="172.40.9.79"
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST="172.40.9.79"
export SPARK_WORKER_HOST="172.40.9.79"
export SPARK_MASTER_IP="172.40.9.79"
```

All above variables are setup in spark-env.sh.

Despite these, the worker will not come up. It is always looking for a master at 127.0.0.1.This is the error i am seeing in /var/log/cassandra/system.log

```
WARN  [worker-register-master-threadpool-8] 2016-10-04 08:02:45,832 SPARK-WORKER Logging.scala:91 - Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:7077
```

Result from dse client-tool shows 127.0.0.1

```
$ dse client-tool -u cassandra -p cassandra spark master-address
spark://127.0.0.1:7077
```

However i am able to access the spark web UI from the LAN IP 172.40.9.79

[Spark Web UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhgIv.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: i had left the listen_address in cassandra.yaml as localhost. Pointing that to 172.40.9.79 fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try add in file spark-defaults.conf this parameter: spark.master                    local[*] or spark.master 172.40.9.79. Maybe this solves your problem

Comment: This did not help, thanks for the suggestion. I fixed it by pointing the listen_address to 172.40.9.79 in cassandra.yaml file